# android seekbar moving draw position on startup

Tags: android, dialog, popup, seekbar

ok, so I have a custom window that pops up and displays an xml file, on that window I'm hoping to put seekbars on there, now I'm having an odd problem that when I load up the popup window, the seekbars are displayed properly, but when I touch one they suddenly redraw to a new position(specifically they are redrawn in the lower left hand corner and at a 90 degree angle), if I change the orientation of the device then everything works fine after that, it's very odd, I'm posting the code below and hoping someone can shed some light as to whats happening ^_^

from the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.exampleProj.sliderPopupWindow"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/myDialog"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.exampleProj.sliderPopup" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the xml file I'm trying to display:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<View android:id="@+id/fakeView"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="0dp" 
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/fakeView" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SeekBar1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SeekBar1" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SeekBar2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SeekBar2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the java file I'm using:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class sliderPopupWindow extends Activity {

SeekBar bar1;
SeekBar bar2;
SeekBar bar3;
WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar1);
    bar2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar2);
    bar3 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar3);
    setContentView(R.layout.sliderwindow);
    params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    params.height = 700;
    params.width = 700;
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}

}
```

not much there yet, rather bare, but it's such an odd problem to happen, I'm hoping someone can give me some insight as to what is happening ^_^

Here are some screenshots to demonstrate the problem. 
The first one demonstrates what happens when one of the bars is first touched, the second shot demonstrates what happens after I rotate the device. After rotation, it looks/works normal (same with if I rotate it back) but the initial touch seems to redraw the seekbar vertically

[image: demonstration of the problem] [image: after rotating device]

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found a workable solution. This problem appears to go away if I change params.width and/or params.height such that params.width != params.height. So once I changed params.height to be 701, the problem went away.